# Ubuntu crashing - How to diagnose

Tags: server, crash, ubuntu-20.04

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu 20.04, with cPanel 106.11, MySQL 8, PHP 8.1, Elasticsearch 7.17.8 and i run magento 2.4.5-p1. Config Server Security & Firewall is enabled.
Every couple of days i get an monitoring alert to say my server doesnt respond to ping and the host has to do a hard reboot, they are getting frustrated with this and say they will turn off monitoring unless i sort this as they have checked all hardware which is fine.
This happens at different times and usually overnight.

I have looked through syslog, mysql log, elasticsearch log, magento 2 logs, apache log, kern.log and i cant find the cause of the issue.
I have enabled "sar" and the RAM usage around the time is 64%, cpu usage is between 5-10%.

What else can i look at to try and diagnose this issue?

Additional info requested by Wilson:

```
select count - https://justpaste.it/6zc95   
show global status - https://justpaste.it/6vqvg   
show global variables - https://justpaste.it/cb52m   
full process list - https://justpaste.it/d41lt   
status - https://justpaste.it/9ht1i   
show engine innodb status - https://justpaste.it/a9uem   
top -b -n 1 - https://justpaste.it/4zdbx   
top -b -n 1 -H - https://justpaste.it/bqt57   
ulimit -a - https://justpaste.it/5sjr4   
iostat -xm 5 3 - https://justpaste.it/c37to   
df -h, df -i, free -h and cat /proc/meminfo - https://justpaste.it/csmwh
htop - https://freeimage.host/i/HAKG0va
```

Server is using nvme drives, 32GB RAM, 6 cores, MySQL is running on same server as litespeed.

Server has not gone down again since posting this but the datacentre usually reboot within 15 - 20 mins and 99% of the time happens overnight. The server is not accessible over ssh when it crashes.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please onsider posting last 100 lines of your Error Log after a failure, before restart.

Comment: Thank Wilson, i have added the links to the requested information

Comment: Could you share the hosting organization name?  Please use myip.ms utility to verify you are really on a DEDICATED server.  How many months has the application been running on the current host?  The results of  your posting to  https://justpaste.it/6zc95  indicate the data_free being 85% of data_length suggests to me that many of your 802 tables NEED to be OPTIMIZEd to reduce overhead in your next scheduled Maintenance Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your instance (should be available in your cpanel as they are all dynamic variables)

```
connect_timeout=30  # from 10 seconds to reduce aborted_connects RPHr of 75 
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to use more of NVME IOPS capacity
thread_cache_size=36  # from 9 to reduce threads_created RPHr of 75
read_rnd_buffer_size=32768  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 5,805
read_buffer_size=524288  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 5,063
```

Many more opportunities exist to improve performance of your instance.
View profile for contact info, please.  We are pushing the one question/one answer planned for this platform.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated those values so we'll see how it goes and i'll contact you through the details in your profile if needed. I'll accept this as a solution because this suggestion will no doubt help performance even if the crashes arent solved yet.